# Which event is fired when Panel is added to DOM?

Tags: extjs

I need to process the DOM after a Grid has been fully rendered and added to DOM. After grid.show() and afterlaout, the dom is still not fully painted. The task is deferred inside ExtJs. How do I get called back when DOM has been fully rendered? I am using ExTjs 3.3.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    listeners:{
       viewready:{fn:doMyRender}, 
       afterlayout:function(){console.log($('.x-grid3-col'));} //finds nothing
    }
);


doMyRender(){
    grid.render(target);
    grid.show();
    $('.x-grid3-col'); //finds nothing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider event :**[afterrender](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.x/docs/source/Component.html#event-Ext.Component-afterrender)**

```
listeners:{
     afterrender: function() {
          //do something
     }
}
```

Comment: It seems unless I queue up my task as well, I can't ensure the dom elements are fully rendered: afterrender: function(){ setTimeout(function(){},100) }

Comment: Right, the dom can be altered at any point...it would be very helpful if you can reproduce it in a jsfillde.